# Manage "Document Type" column for each library which have different options

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, administration, managed-property, crawled-property

We have this case:

1. A site with 10 document libraries
2. For each document library we need to tag the documents with a managed metadata column named "Document Type"
3. Use the PnP Modern search web part, to be able to filter and search the documents using the "Document Type"

I found 2 approaches to follow:

1. **First Approach**. Create a single managed metadata site column named "Document Type" >> with all the options and user will select the related term.

**Advantage**:

- Simple
- Single managed metadata property to be used inside the PnP Modern search web part

**Disadvantage**:

- Users will get all the options even the ones not related to the current document library, when tagging the documents inside the document libraries.

2. **Second Approach**. Create 10 columns named "<>Document Type". each column will only contain the related the related options for the current document library

**Advantage**:

- Users will only get the options related to the current document library

**Disadvantage**:

- not sure how we can filter the documents from all the libraries using a single column? For example, can i configure a single `RefinableString` managed property which have the 10 underlying crawl properties? so i will have a single managed property that span the 10 crawl properties and which i can use inside the PnP Modern search web part? will this work?

Comment: One managed property with multiple crawled properties assigned to it should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer to your last question is, **Yes**.

You can use a single `RefinableString` managed property in your SharePoint site and add mapping to 10 different crawled properties under single managed property.

Then you can use that new managed property in PnP Modern search web parts and it should work for you.

Check below links for more information:

1. [Overview of crawled and managed properties in SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/technical-reference/crawled-and-managed-properties-overview) - most of the properties are available in SharePoint Online as well
2. [PnP Modern Search Filters Web Part](https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search/usage/search-filters/)